# Anyway to get a list of files/directories in node.js in one call

Tags: performance, node.js, fs

In node.js (fs), we can get the list of all files+directories using `fs.readdir()`, now to get the files/directories apart we need to call `stat = fs.stat()` and on the result call `stat.isDirectory()` or `stat.isFile()` on each of the returned values (paths).

Is there a better (perf-wise) way to do this?

Comment: You can solve specific problems with `fs.readdir()` using regular expressions. For example, if you want to process only `.js` files you can filter `fs.readdir()` response by matching `/\.js$/` regexp. But general solution includes calling `fs.stat()`.

Comment: This will not tell me whether a result entry is a file or directory.